# How to apply css to a dynamically created div?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Here I have a function that creates a div box, but I wish to move the styling to a external css file. When I do that, however, the boxes are no longer styled. How could I apply the css to the div boxes that are created dynamically? Is it even worth moving the styling to an external css file?

```
    function createBox() {
        var box = document.createElement("DIV");
        box.setAttribute("id", "box");
        document.body.appendChild(box);
        boxStyle = box.style;
        boxStyle.position = "absolute"; 
        boxStyle.background = '#'+Math.floor(Math.random()*16777215).toString(16);
        boxStyle.width = Math.floor(Math.random()*50) + '%';
        boxStyle.height = Math.floor(Math.random()*50) + '%';
        boxStyle.top = Math.floor(Math.random()*100) + '%';
        boxStyle.left = Math.floor(Math.random()*100) + '%';
    }
```

EDIT: I realized that what's been causing me grief in my CSS is that I was using Math.floor and Math.random() functions that don't work in CSS. Silly me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are creating div with id `#box`, add the following css in the external css file and include it in the `<head>`

```
#box {
          position: absolute;
          background: red;
          width: 90px;
          height: 50px;
          left: 100;
          top: 100;
        }
```

It looks like you will creating more `boxes` of with same `id` `#box`. I would recommend you to create based on classes. And use css to apply the styles based on the classname.

```
function createBox() {
        var box = document.createElement("DIV");
        box.setAttribute("class", "boxes");
        document.body.appendChild(box);
    }
```

css:

```
.boxes {
    position: absolute;
    background: red;
    width: 90px;
    height: 50px;
    left: 100;
    top: 100;
 }
```

**[demo](http://jsbin.com/safiv/1)**

Answer (score 1):

You can apply CSS to dynamicly created items the same way for usual HTML. All you need is to target the correct selector.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mnIhj

Answer (score 0):

You can gather the properties you wish to apply on the div box in a class in external style sheet, and use:

```
function createBox() {
        var box = document.createElement("DIV");
        box.setAttribute("id", "box");
        box.className = "boxStyle";
        document.body.appendChild(box);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this chnages in your script,

```
 function createBox() {
    var box = document.createElement("DIV");
    box.setAttribute("id", "box");
    document.body.appendChild(box);
    var boxStyle = document.getElementById("box").style;
    boxStyle.position = "absolute"; 
    boxStyle.background = '#'+Math.floor(Math.random()*16777215).toString(16);
    boxStyle.width = Math.floor(Math.random()*50) + '%';
    boxStyle.height = Math.floor(Math.random()*50) + '%';
    boxStyle.top = Math.floor(Math.random()*100) + '%';
    boxStyle.left = Math.floor(Math.random()*100) + '%';
}
```